# IntellijIdea "Contract clause '_-> null' is violated" what this mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a piece of code :

```
public static Model parseModelObject(JSONObject objectJSON) {
    Project project = new Project();

    project.id = objectJSON.optInt(ID);
    project.title = objectJSON.optString(TITLE);
    project.idAuthor = objectJSON.optString(ID_AUTHOR);
    project.endDate = objectJSON.optString(END_DATE);
    project.aimAmount = objectJSON.optString(AIM_AMOUNT);
    project.currentAmount = objectJSON.optString(CURRENT_AMOUNT);
    project.createdAt = objectJSON.optString(_CREATED_AT);
    project.updatedAt = objectJSON.optString(_UPDATED_AT);
    project.status = objectJSON.optString(STATUS);
    project.description = objectJSON.optString(DESCRIPTION);
    project.logo = objectJSON.optString(LOGO);
    project.background = objectJSON.optString(BACKGROUND);
    return project;
}
```

And on line

```
 return project;
```

Intellij Idea show up warning :

> Contract clause '_-> null` is violated

What this mean?

Comment: Is Project a subclass of Model?  The return type is Model; you return a Project instance.

Comment: Seems a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127667#tab=History) which has been fixed?

Comment: @duffymo, no changes, while i changed return type to Project.